# What’s the most straightforward way to typeset theorems etc. when the numbering is entirely manual?

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I’m using LaTeX to typeset some homework, and since we’re assigned problems scattered throughout our textbook I have to enter the problem number for each problem I typeset. I’d like these problems to look like this:

> **Problem 4.15.** Prove that for every prime *p*, …

As far as I can tell, all of the straightforward ways to do this with `amsthm` will produce labels like

> **Problem** (4.15)**.**

or

> **4.15. Problem.**

neither of which is quite what I want. Most of the samples I’ve found online are complicated by the fact that they support automatic numbering, but that’s not necessary (or even really useful) for me. I did come up with this:

```
\newenvironment{myproblem}[1][]
    {\vspace{1em} \noindent \textbf{Problem #1.}}
    {\vspace{1em}}
```

It produces the output I want, give or take an imperceptible amount of spacing, but this feels like a kludge. Is there a way to get what I want using `amsthm` or `ntheorem` or something like that?

Comment: So you don't want automatic numbering? If so, may I ask you why? What do "4" and "15" represent in your example?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina As I said, we’re assigned a smattering of problems from a textbook (e.g. “problem 12 from chapter 4 and problem 5 from chapter 5”), and in order to include the problem number in my answers I need to use wildly non-sequential values (4.12 and 5.5 in this example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `thmtools` package as a front-end for `amsthm` to define your own theorem style. You can suppress the automatic numbering using the `numbered=no` option, and use the additional note field to manually introduce the numbering. Notice however that this approach has two drawbacks: 1) You loose the possibility of cross-referencing your problems. 2) Manual numbering is error-prone.

Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.5em,
numbered=no,
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}[4.15]
Prove that for every prime $p$,
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}[3.12]
Prove that every integer
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As I already mentioned, the previous solution annihilates cross-referencing. Here's another approach that allows you to cross-reference your problems. I am assuming that the two-fold counter for the problems has its firs component (the "4" in your example) associated to an already defined counter (the one of a sectional unit, as it is customary), and that only the second component (the "15" in your example) will be manually introduced (again a possible source of errors).

In the following example I used `amsthm` to define a new theorem-like structure of `definition` style; this new structure will be numbered subordinately within sections. Then I wrapped this definition using a new environment with a mandatory argument that will be used to set the proper value to the second component of the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}[section]

\newenvironment{problem}[1]
  {\setcounter{prob}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}\begin{prob}}
  {\end{prob}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\begin{problem}{15}\label{test1}
Prove that for every prime $p$,
\end{problem}
\section{Test}
\begin{problem}{8}\label{test2}
Prove that for every ring $R$,
\end{problem}
We see in Problems~\ref{test1} and~\ref{test2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t need the ability to cross-reference so this will work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler solution that also copes with cross references.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem*{probleminn}{Problem \@currentlabel}
\newenvironment{problem}[1]
  {\def\@currentlabel{#1}\probleminn}{\endprobleminn}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}{4.14} 
Prove that $2$ is prime.
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}{4.15}\label{bigproblem}
Prove that $2+2=4$.
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}{5.5}\label{easyone}
Prove that every even integer greater than $2$ is the sum of two primes.
\end{problem}

I can solve \ref{easyone}, but I'm stuck with \ref{bigproblem}.
\end{document}
```

Defining `\@currentlabel` is what's needed for assigning the correct value to the `\label`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{thmtools}
    \declaretheorem[numberwithin={}]{theorem}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        something
    \end{theorem}
     \begin{theorem}
        something
    \end{theorem}
   \end{document}
```

[image]