# Alternative numbering for theorem

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems, counters, amsthm

I am using `thmtools` as a front end to `amsthm` and I have a definition environment as follows.

```
\declaretheorem[
    style=mydefinitionstyle,
    name=Definition,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{definition}
```

And what I want is another environment, say called `definitionAlt`, which would be used to give an alternative definition of the one just given, i.e., it uses the same number/counter as the definition just given but adds an "a" (or "b" or whatever), without incrementing the counter, and cross-referencing would still work.

```
\begin{definition}
\label{def:main_definition}
This is a definition which is numbered 1.1
\end{definition}

\begin{definitionAlt}
\label{def:alt_definition}
This is an alternative definition to the preceding one, which is automatically numbered 1.1a
\end{definitionAlt}
```

I have seen similar questions such as 
[What’s the most straightforward way to typeset theorems etc. when the numbering is entirely manual?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28858/whats-the-most-straightforward-way-to-typeset-theorems-etc-when-the-numbering?rq=1)

which does some manual theorem numbering, but I cant find an answer that does exactly what I want.

Doe anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This has come up several types. This is possible with counters. Just define a new counter, call it defntype, which is `\alph` and hook that counter to this environment.

Comment: I think what I am trying to do is closer to this - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101814/using-amsthm-to-number-examples-how-do-i-account-for-altered-examples-i-e-1?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheorem[
    style=mydefinitionstyle,
    name=Definition,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{definition}

\declaretheorem[
    style=mydefinitionstyle,
    name=Definition,
    numberwithin=definition,
]{definitionAlt}
\renewcommand\thedefinitionAlt{\thedefinition\alph{definitionAlt}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Testing Alternate Definitions Counter} 
\begin{definition}
\label{def:main_definition}
This is a definition which is numbered 1.1
\end{definition}

\begin{definitionAlt}
\label{def:alt_definitiona}
This is an alternative definition to the preceding one, which is automatically numbered 1.1a
\end{definitionAlt} 

\begin{definitionAlt}
\label{def:alt_definitionb}
This is an alternative definition to the preceding one, which is automatically numbered 1.1b.
\end{definitionAlt} 

\begin{definition}
\label{def:another_main_definition}
This is a definition which is numbered 1.2.
\end{definition}
And, of course, I can refer to my second alternate definition, the definition \ref{def:alt_definitionb} and my another definition, the definition \ref{def:another_main_definition} quite well!

\begin{definitionAlt}
\label{def:new_alt_definitiona}
This is an alternative definition to the preceding one, which is automatically numbered 1.2a.
\end{definitionAlt} 

begin{definition}
\label{def:yet_another_main_definition}
This is a definition which is numbered 1.3.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel) for his help on this one!.

---

**The Output**

Here it goes:

[image: defntypeenviron.png]

Comment: @conorsomahony Glad to have helped! If this answer is what you were looking for, could you please accept this by clicking on the tick mark besides this answer? :)

Comment: I just noticed one small issue, the alph part of the counter doesn't get reset, so If I add another definitionAlt after Definition 1.2 - then this gets the number 1.2c, instead of 1.2a again...

Comment: @conorsomahony Oh, good catch, I'll update my answer, just a few moments please... :)

Comment: @conorsomahony See my update. :)

Comment: @kan -- er, you want to repair the text for def. 1.2a -- it now purportedly refers to itself.  (i don't want to make the change, since i would undoubtedly bollix up the output.)

Comment: @kan thanks very much, exactly what i was looking for, very elegant answer!

Comment: @barbarabeeton not sure I follow what I must fix... could you please edit it so that, I can compile the code and fix the picture. Thanks!

Comment: @kan -- the "which" in definition 1.2a has "the preceding one" as its antecedent, and the preceding one is numbered 1.2.  what i think you mean is "This definition, which is automatically numbered 1.2a, is an alternative to the preceding one."  (i didn't want to make the change unless i was absolutely certain what you meant.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton oooh! Will fix! :-)