# Automatic label numbering and corresponding citation

Tags: cross-referencing

I use  the PDFLaTeX to design the exercise template.
I want the labels of exercises are automatically given
according to the Chapter number and the Exercise number,
and I also want to show the Exercise number
in the bookmark of the PDF files.
Inspired by [What’s the most straightforward way to typeset theorems etc. when the numbering is entirely manual?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28858),
I try the following codes:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exx}[1]{\def\@currentlabel{#1}
\ex\label{\@currentlabel}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Exercise~~\@currentlabel}{\@currentlabel}
}{\endex}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\exref}[1]{Exercise~\textup{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Hello Chapter 4}

\begin{exx}
Exercise A.
\end{exx}

\begin{exx}
Exercise B.
\end{exx}

By \exref{4.1} and \exref{4.2}

\end{document}
```

It works, but some problems occur, which shows

```
Exercise 4.1. xercise A.
Exercise 4.2. xercise B.
By Exercise 4.1 and Exercise 4.2
```

i.e., the first letters of the Exercises are missing!!!
Of course, we can avoid this by replacing  `\begin{exx}{}` with `\begin{exx}`,
but I don't want this unless I want redefine  new lables for the Exercises, namely,

```
\begin{exx}
Exercise A.
\end{exx}
\exref{4.1}
```

and

```
\begin{exx}{newLabel41}
Exercise A.
\end{exx}
\exref{newLabel41}
```

give the same results. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably interested in an optional argument rather than a mandatory one. With the latter - your current setup using `\newenvironment{exx}[1]` - it gobbles the first letter in the environment body as the mandatory argument. With an optional argument - using `\newenvironment{exx}[1][]` - [you can test whether it was used or not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764) and use a different `\label`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]
\newenvironment{exx}[1][]{% 
  \begin{ex}
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \label{\@currentlabel}%
    \else
      \label{#1}%
    \fi
    \pdfbookmark[1]{Exercise~~\@currentlabel}{\@currentlabel}
}{%
  \end{ex}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\exref}[1]{Exercise~\textup{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Hello Chapter 4}

\begin{exx}
Exercise A.
\end{exx}

\begin{exx}
Exercise B.
\end{exx}

See \exref{4.1} and \exref{4.2}, but also \exref{ex:next}.

\begin{exx}[ex:next]
Exercise C.
\end{exx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is of great help to me, thank you very much@Werner